# Calculation of residue of $\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you please show me how to find the residue of 
$\dfrac{x^2}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^3}$ where $a>0$ at $ai$?

Edit: Thanks to one of the answers I now see that I can use the residue theory and take the limit of x goes to ai.

Comment: PLEASE SHOW YOUR WORK

Comment: what have you tried. Where live $x$ ? in $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio There's no need to shout! (Also, "show your working" or "what have your tried" isn't necessarily the best thing to comment in these circumstances. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28072/what-have-you-tried) for a discussion.)

Comment: @user1729 I am sorry that my keyboard became weird that I couldn't type small case letter.

Answer (score 3):

The pole is third-order, [so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles) the residue is $$\frac12\lim_{x\to ai}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{x^2}{(x+ai)^3}=\left.\left(\frac{6x^2}{(x+ai)^5}-\frac{6x}{(x+ai)^4}+\frac{1}{(x+ai)^3}\right)\right|_{x=ai},$$where because I was lazy I calculated the second derivative [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+of+x%5E2%2F%28x%2Bc%29%5E3). So the residue is$$\frac{3i}{16a^3}-\frac{3i}{8a^3}+\frac{i}{8a^3}=\frac{-i}{16a^3}.$$I'm guessing you plan on multiplying this by $2\pi i$ any moment now, which would give $\frac{\pi}{8a^3}$. (Indeed, $x=a\tan t$ shows $\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{x^2dx}{(x^2+a^2)^3}=\frac{1}{4a^3}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^22tdt=\frac{\pi}{8a^3}$.)

Comment: Thanks very much. May I ask how did you determine the order of the pole?

Comment: @Dec1337bravo Because the function is $\color{green}{\frac{x^2}{(x+ai)^3}}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{1}{(x-ai)^3}}$. The green part is finite but nonzero (indeed, $-\frac{i}{8a}$) at $x=ai$; the red part gives the pole's order.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the formula somewhere but could not understand it as well as you explained

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=u+ai$ and consider the residue at $u=0$ of
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^3}
&=\frac{u^2+2uai-a^2}{\left(u^2+2uai\right)^3}\\
&=\frac{u^2+2uai-a^2}{-8a^3u^3i\left(1+\frac{u}{2ai}\right)^3}\\
&=\frac{u^2+2uai-a^2}{-8a^3u^3i}\left(1-\frac{3u}{2ai}-\frac{3u^2}{2a^2}+O\!\left(u^3\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
The coefficient of $\frac1u$ is
$$
\frac{1-3+\frac32}{-8a^3i}=-\frac1{16a^3}i
$$